# Uploading images using Prestashop Api and SoapUI

Tags: api, prestashop, soapui, image-uploading

I am using PrestaShop API. I want to upload/updated pictures using SoapUI. But I am having a problem with this.

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <image>
       <content encode="base64">....(base64 Content)....</content>  
    </image>    
</prestashop>
```

I give the product ID in the URL section, then POST.

I get this error

```
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <errors>
      <error>
         <code>66</code>
         <message>Unable to save this image</message>
      </error>
   </errors>
</prestashop>
```

I'm waiting for your help.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have more code you can show us?

Comment: Can you show the screen shot of raw request?

Comment: I do not have more codes.


You can examine this link for raw request ;   http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Chapter+9+-+Image+management